# "Cannot reference 'SAPServiceProviderConnection' before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: android, tizen

I import a project SimpleSAPProvider (http://developer.samsung.com/what-is-new/blog/2014/Tutorial-How-to-build-a-Basic-Integrated-Gear-Application) provided by Samsung,in Android Studio. It makes one error ""Cannot reference 'SAPServiceProviderConnection' before supertype constructor has been called." and i am unable to compile it. It works fine in Eclipse.

Here is the code..

```
    public SAPServiceProvider() {
        super(TAG, SAPServiceProviderConnection.class);//Showing Error
        Log.d("SAP PROVIDER", "SERVICE CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a legit code. use it in Eclipse it will work properly.Android Studio however shows error

Comment: yeah i know it,,,do you know any hack to work it in Android Studio?